# How to get the distance of Jupiter from the sun?

Tags: curated-data, astronomy, distance

I am aware of the command `AstronomicalData["Jupiter", "Distance"]` from which I can get the distance between the earth and Jupiter. Is there any way to use `AstronomicalData` to get the distance between the sun and Jupiter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps naïve:

```
Norm@AstronomicalData["Jupiter", "Position"]
(*
  7.74204*10^11
  edit .... copy/paste error corrected
*)
```

Checking some consistence

```
EuclideanDistance @@ (AstronomicalData[#, "Position"] & /@ {"Earth", "Jupiter"}) == 
                                            AstronomicalData["Jupiter", "Distance"]

(*
 True
*)
```

Comment: @Kuba I can't comment. I've never been in Jupiter.

Comment: @Kuba My knowledge of astronomy is only commensurable with my manners: It doesn't suffice to get surprised.

Comment: @Kuba Well, I get a `7` now. Eppur si muove;

Answer (score 16):

Offered as an alternative to getting the same information and a check on it, one can also get this measurement from a WolframAlpha query:

[image]

...

Of some interest, by these measurements Jupiter appears to have moved quite a ways further from the Sun since belisarius's answer just some 11 hours ago.

67.74204*10^11  vs  7.74232*10^11

---

WolframAlpha can also give one a plot of Jupiter's position in orbit (although not a particularly satisfying one):

[image]

If, Jupiter had crossed its perihelion (the point it passes closest to the sun, which should correspond to the fastest part of its orbit) could it have moved as much as it appears to have moved between belisarius's measure and mine?

Any astronomers or astro physicists about?

Comment: Interesting ... do you think we are solving for two different Jupiters?

Comment: @belisarius - Perhaps just slipping glimpses of parallel universes. More (or less given one's point of view) seriously, I ran the Wolfram Alpha query and your code and almost the same time and got essentially identical values (7.743 x^11 meters).  I just ran The Wolfram Alpha query again and it comes out 7.744*10^11.  Not as big a move, but a move.

Comment: @belisarius I thought at first you'd forgotten to compensate for the great altitude at which you train...

Comment: @belisarius Ok, I've deleted old comments